# Как сделать прозрачную таблицу для Chrome?

Tags: html, css

```
  td {
    opacity: 0.8; /* Полупрозрачность таблицы */
    filter: alpha(Opacity=80); /* Для IE */
   }
```

В опере работает, а вот в хроме нет, в чем дело? Есть ли способ сделать прозрачность таблицы для Хрома?

Comment: гуглить влом?

Comment: В хроме это должно работать!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/4mKQD/. Всё в Хроме также должно быть. Откройте эту ссылку в хроме.

Может быть у вас `background-color` применяется к таблице, а opacity отдельно к ячейкам? Так не будет работать.

http://jsfiddle.net/sCDwr/ Вот пример, только текст прозрачным стал.

Answer (score 2):

```
-webkit-opacity: 0,8;
```

А вообще лучше используйте прозрачные картинки 1х1 в формате png.